# Flyway & Log4J Logging

Tags: flyway

I am trying to get logging to work with Flyway / Log4J / FileAppender. I realize there are several questions related to this topic on SO and elsewhere, and they all tend to say something along the lines of "if log4j is in your classpath, Flyway will use it automatically".

However, after many hours of ensuring I have log4j in the classpath, trying countless configuration options, and working with both log4j 1.x and 2.x, I am unable to see a logfile get created by log4j. I also don't see any type of error message or pointer indicating what might be wrong, even when running the Flyway command line client with the '-X' option.

I am admittedly not a Java person, so perhaps this is completely obvious to those well versed in Java (and I apologize if that's the case) -- but, I think I (and others) would benefit from an actual example or quick set of steps to get log4j working with Flyway. Certainly, there is more than ensuring log4j is in your classpath since log4j requires configuration, etc.

What version(s) of log4j should we be using? What does a working example config file look like for Flyway?

I think Flyway is great, but could use a bit more info on getting logging up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is will only be supported for Flyway Command-line starting with 4.0: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1075

Comment: Any word on when 4.0 is targeted for (roughly)?

Answer (score 1):

Put this artifacts in classpath and use any log4j config file.

Gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.13'
```